# Can we add query keywords to the code highlighter?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Their are several keywords not added to the Syntex Highlighter that I would suggest adding. First I assume that the Query highlighter works on main Keywords used in many languages to help us programmers out.

Its missing the highlight of the following keywords "From", "Order By", and "Descending" in the recent addition to VB.net is the LINQ language syntax (its also in c#). A way for programmers to run database queries against .net objects. It's very neat.

However I copied over my query to answer my own question when I found these keywords were not highlighted. They're highlighted in Visual Studio and recognized as code keywords.

Here's the code:

```
Dim bestCat As ArticleCategory = (From cat In Categories
                                  Order By cat.tempCount Descending, cat.Name
                                  Select cat).First
```

I've simplified it for showing my example.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556274/345442

If you could help this patch request move along nicely: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=182

So keep informed of patch progress... I'm not writing it.

Comment: +1 As this is so central to the success of SO I'm sure the team is always working hard on this. If I'm not mistaken, code syntax highlighting uses a Google API?

Comment: Yep, I've added a patch request.